# How to post Drupal nodes from Excel VBA using REST

Tags: rest, excel, vba

Using latest Drupal 6 and Services 3.x module, with REST server configured. Created a new content type called 'test, no required cck fields, body field is removed. I've seen several examples of this same method for testing a REST service.

Can get it to GET and DELETE nodes from VBA, but it won't POST or PUT (create or update). Have read dozens of pages and questions about this, REST server configs seem good and VBA submission seems good.

```
Dim MyURL as String
MyURL = "http://example.com/rest/node?node[type]=test&node[title]=newtestnode"
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

With objHTTP
    .Open "POST", MyURL, False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    .send (MyURL)
End With
```

Status returned on POST and PUT is "Unauthorized: Access denied for user 0 "anonymous", response is null. The denied error originates from inside Services module.

I've verified anonymous can create this type via browser, and I'm able to DELETE from VBA so I'm sure my perms and setup is in order. I've found many examples from PHP, Perl, Java, Ruby, but none from Excel VBA. I also tested this in another server and drupal website, all same results. Services issue queue has nothing like this.

Can it not be done? Very frustrating!